# What explains the connection between the boat's name and Lee's daughter?

Tags: analysis, manchester-by-the-sea

I loved *Manchester by the Sea* but am not sure about the connection between the name of the boat and the review that it is also the name of one of Lee's daughters.
Are we supposed to believe that

1. This was their mother's name?
2. That it was once Lee's boat?
3. It's just another metaphor in the movie to tie the bother's stories together?

Answer (score 3):

Boat name "Claudia Marie" was based on their mother's name, which got clear by the tombstone in the funeral scene

[image][image]

Lee's daughter name was not Claudia Marie but it was Suzy Chandler, also confirmed on [IMDb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4034228/fullcredits?ref_=tt_cl_sm#cast).